# SUBTIME returning incorrect value on time difference

Tags: mysql

I have two times, start time and end time, end time is always greater than start which is my case is:

SUBTIME('22:00', '06:00')

This returns 16:00 because its considering it as same date but 06:00 is greater so the difference should come out as 08:00 hours. I tried swapping but it gives -16 instead.

Is there a way to get the correct value without adding date to time values?

Ended up doing this

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE check_in BETWEEN CONCAT(schedule_date,' ',start_time) AND (CASE WHEN(SUBTIME(end_time, start_time) < 0) THEN CONCAT(schedule_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY,' ',end_time) ELSE CONCAT(schedule_date,' ',end_time) END)
```

Comment: You can add a CASE statement - adding 24 hours to end times that are 'less' than start times.

Comment: Thanks looks interesting let me try

Comment: So 22:00 is the _start_ time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then don't use simple times, but dates.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CONCAT('1970-01-01 ', '22:00'), CONCAT('1970-01-02 ', '06:00'));
```

This returns `8`, when you want to have it as `08:00`, try this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, CONCAT('1970-01-01 ', '22:00'), CONCAT('1970-01-02 ', '06:00')));
```

Comment: Thanks if i couldn't find an answer i ll go this way